# find: git: No such file or directory through script in crontab

Tags: git, shell, find, cron

I am trying to create a script to run in crontab but i am having problems with command locations when i try to use it under crontab daemon.

Already made some tests with the script and seems to be working fine.

Here is it:

```
# I add this cd because of crontab location
cd ~/Documents/gitrepobackup/    

find . -type d -depth 1 -exec git --git-dir={} --work-tree=$PWD/{} fetch origin \; >> git_backup_update.log 2>&1
```

And this is the output that i receive at that log:

```
find: git: No such file or directory
```

This is also the entry that i have added in crontab:

```
* * * * * ~/Documents/gitrepobackup/git_backup_update.sh
```

Anyone?

Comment: Adjust your `PATH`. The popular implementations of `cron` allow to set the environment variables in _crontab_: `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:...`. Alternatively, pass an absolute path to `git`, e.g. `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, that is one way to go, i have made 'which git' and discover the location and then just add it in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read at http://man.cx/crontab(5), the `PATH` environment variable is set to `/usr/bin:/bin`. If `git` is not in one of those places, your script will not find it. If you want your own `PATH` environment variable set, you can configure it, or you use abolute paths to the executables that are not found in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this, but since i only had problems with git, i made,

```
which git
```

discover where it was and just add the location at git,

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -exec /usr/local/git/bin/git --git-dir={} --work-tree=$PWD/{} fetch origin \; >> git_backup_update.log 2>&1
```